# How to use whitespace in procmailrc recipe destination path?

Tags: path, mutt, email, whitespace, procmail

I use Mutt Maildir for storage mails.
I created one mailbox like this `Stack Exchange/`. (whitespace between Stack and Exchange here)

procmailrc recipe:

```
:0
* From: .*Stack\ Exchange
Stack Exchange/
```

But upper recipe destination setting failed. after test and watch the log file.
I found procmail jumped through `Exchange/`, deliver email to `Stack` **file**, instead of `Stack` **maildir folder**, nor `Stack Exchange/` **maildir folder**.

And I googled procmail settings, FAQ etc. not found relative problems.

So, does anybody knows how to escape whitespace here ?

Comment: While it's perfectly valid to have spaces in file and directory names, doing so is likely to cause you all manner of unnecessary annoyances and problems.  In other words: Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I hit myself in the head with a hammer". Doctor: "Don't do that then".

Comment: If you would ask "How can I escape whitespace here?", you would prevent people from correctly answer "Yes, someone knows." and also prevent errors ("anybody know" without "s", the space before the question mark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it isn't mentioned in the procmail manual, I believe (I haven't checked) that putting a backslash before the space removes its special meaning (like in other parts of procmail).

```
:0
* From: .*Stack\ Exchange
Stack\ Exchange/
```

If that doesn't work, use a variable.

```
STACKEXCHANGE_MAILBOX=Stack Exchange
:0
* From: .*Stack\ Exchange
$STACKEXCHANGE_MAILBOX
```

Comment: You're right, I forget put slash `/` after `Stack\ Exhcange/Android`, so that I can not use mutt to find mails in `Android`. It should be `Stack\ Exchange/Android/`, my fault.

Comment: You need to use the final slash if using Maildir and NOT to use it, if using Mbox. The backslash before space does escape the space as expected.